# Can I use a self signed cert with the SONOS self tests?

Tags: sonos

I am in the process of setting up the SONOS self test suite to run against my local development machine. I have set up SSL using IIS EXpress and a self signed certificate.

But trying to run a test result in:

```
2017-08-16 11:39:10,776 [DEBUG] SONOS.suds.client - headers = {'SOAPAction': '"http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1#getSessionId"', 'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'User-Agent': 'Linux UPnP/1.0 Sonos/33.12-29310 (Self-Test)'}
2017-08-16 11:39:11,622 [CRITICAL] SONOS.sonos.smapi.smapiclient - Partner Exception error: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)>
```

By browsing around it seem like I can disable SSL verification in python somewhere but I fail to locate the correct place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sonos does not support self signed certs for self test. You can safely ignore the errors you'll get running self test under these conditions, and focus on the rest of the suite.

When you have made your server available at its actual endpoint, you can start to pay attention to the ssl tests then.